# Is there a way to wrap text when you're running a script that prints in Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm

I'm running a particular Python program for testing purposes, and the lines outputted are sometimes very long. Moving the horizontal-scroll bar is a very painful way to read the output, but I don't want to alter the code to print newlines  every 80 characters or some other hack like that... Is there a way to wrap outputted text when running a program in the *run* window? I know that this can be done for the console in **View -> Active Editor -> Use Soft Wraps**, however this doesn't seem to impact the *Run* window.

Maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, found it -- there's a **Use Soft Wraps** options right next to the blue down arrow *in the Run Window* that you can toggle on and off, that isn't accessible from the main menu.

Might as well leave this up in case someone has the same question.